# Reading *.lyr file in QGIS when no access to Arc2SLD or ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: qgis, layer-file

Does anyone know how to open .lyr files in QGIS without having access to ArcGIS or to Arc2SLD?

Perhaps there is a plugin or open source program that could do it.

Comment: The answer you directed me to doesn't answer the question as I don't have access to ArcGIS or Arc2SLD.

Comment: I'll run it past our IT department, but if possible id like to find a way of doing it via QGIS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible for QGIS to directly read `.lyr` files as they are in a **binary format**. QGIS is designed to read `.qlr` files as they are in an **XML format**.

This [post](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/arcgis-lyr-files-and-qgis-qlr-files) gives a nice description detailing the main differences between the two file types. The following is a summary quoted from the link provided:

> - **So can you use a lyr with QGIS?**
>
>   *Nope.*
> - **Can you use a qlr with ArcGIS?**
>
>   *Nope.*
> - **Can you define symbology in ArcGIS from a lyr file?**
>
>   *Yes! Just import your symbology and choose your lyr and if the attribution matches you are good.*
> - **Can you define symbology in QGIS from a qlr file?**
>
>   *No – but that is what qml and sld files are for. Save those from your property menu and you can use those to symbolize other data.*
> - **Can you open a lyr in a text editor and see how it works?**
>
>   *NO…I think the greatest shortcoming of lyr is this.*
> - **Can you open a qlr in a text editor and see how it works?**
>
>   *YES…it’s an XML based file.*